# turtlebot2 kobuki turns itself off when cmd_velocity > 1

Tags: ros, turtlebot, kobuki, linear-velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The setup:
I currently have 2 turtlebots and a workstation all communicating via `multimaster_fkie`. The workstation only launches the `multimaster_discovery` node while the turtlebots bringup both `multimaster_discovery` and `multimaster_sync` nodes. The turtlebots have been configured to ignore one another so that only communication with the workstation is possible.

The problem occurs when a velocity command that is "too high" is published from the workstation. The workstation publishes velocity commands to both the turtlebots under topics `/master_cmd` and `/slave_cmd` (there is no real master/slave implementation going on unless you count the workstation as the master and the turtlebots as slaves)

I have a simple implementation where the turtlebots listen for either `/master[slave]_cmd` velocity command from the workstation and subsequently publishes this command to the kobuki base. I have turned all other diagnostics off so only the kobuki base should initialized. (My launch file can be seen pasted below)

Currently I have many different implementations all yielding the same result. I have tried defining my own nodlet so a constant twist message is published. I have a full node which does the same thing. and I have a node runnning on the turtlebot netbook while another node from the workstation computer sends commands.

In all most all cases I am able to send a velocity of up to 1.0 (I assume m/s)

When I change from:  `msg.linear.x = 1` to `msg.linear.x = 2` and run everything as before the turtlebot kobuki sounds the offline jingle and everything stops. When I kill the node trying to publish the velocity commands the online jingle can be heard.

Throughout this I can `rostopic list/echo` all the topics and even verify that the correct value is being sent.

The problem is very weird because if all the velocities are below 1 both turtlebots act as excepted. It is only when one is commanded to go faster than 1 that the problem occurs.

Why does the kobuki turn it self off when too high a velocity is received?

```
<launch>
  <!-- Turtlebot --> 
  <arg name="base"              default="$(env TURTLEBOT_BASE)"         doc="mobile base type [create, roomba]"/>
  <arg name="battery"           default="$(env TURTLEBOT_BATTERY)"      doc="kernel provided locatio for battery info, use /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 in 2.6 or earlier kernels." />
  <arg name="stacks"            default="$(env TURTLEBOT_STACKS)"       doc="stack type displayed in visualisation/simulation [circles, hexagons]"/>
  <arg name="3d_sensor"         default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"    doc="3d sensor types [kinect, asux_xtion_pro]"/>
  <arg name="simulation"        default="$(env TURTLEBOT_SIMULATION)"   doc="set flags to indicate this turtle is run in simulation mode."/>
  <arg name="serialport"        default="$(env TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT)"  doc="used by create to configure the port it is connected on [/dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyS0]"/>
  <arg name="robot_name"        default="$(env TURTLEBOT_NAME)"         doc="used as a unique identifier and occasionally to preconfigure root namespaces, gateway/zeroconf ids etc."/>
  <arg name="robot_type"        default="$(env TURTLEBOT_TYPE)"         doc="just in case you are considering a 'variant' and want to make use of this."/>
  <arg name="manager"       default="mobile_base_nodelet_manager"   doc=""/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="$(arg simulation)"/>

 
  <arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" />
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />

  <!-- important generally, but specifically utilised by the current app manager -->  
  <param name="robot/name" value="$(optenv ROBOT turtlebot)"/>
  <param name="robot/type" value="turtlebot"/>
  


  <!-- mobile base nodelet manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base_nodelet_manager" args="manager"/>
  
  <!-- mobile base --> 
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base" args="load kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet $(arg manager)">
    <rosparam file="$(find kobuki_node)/param/base.yaml" command="load"/>
    <param name="device_port" value="$(arg serialport)" />

    <remap from="mobile_base/odom" to="odom"/>
    <!-- Don't do this - force applications to use a velocity mux for redirection  
       <remap from="mobile_base/commands/velocity" to="cmd_vel"/> -->
    <remap from="mobile_base/enable" to="enable"/>
    <remap from="mobile_base/disable" to="disable"/>
    <remap from="mobile_base/joint_states" to="joint_states"/>
  </node>
 </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262498/turtlebot2-kobuki-turns-itself-off-when-cmd_velocity-%3E-1/) by [mesteinf](https://answers.ros.org/users/30449/mesteinf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not quite sure I understand your problem description: is the problem that the TBs just stop?

Is 1 m/s a valid velocity for a Kobuki TB? According to [the specifications](http://kobuki.yujinrobot.com/about2/), the maximum is 0.7m/s (this is also mentioned on [wiki/Setup the Navigation Stack for TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Setup%20the%20Navigation%20Stack%20for%20TurtleBot)):

> - **Functional Specification**
>
>   - Maximum translational velocity: 70 cm/s
>   - ..

I can imagine that the controller shuts down on an invalid command input. 1 m/s already seems quite far outside the specs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mesteinf](https://answers.ros.org/users/30449/mesteinf/) on 2017-05-25**:
I have seen that before and maybe just mistook it for 7m/s but why then, when I have only 1 turtlebot can I see a difference in the rate the wheel spins when commanded to go at 1 vs 3? I would expect both cases to yield 0.7 but I do not observe this. There is distinctly more 'buzzing' and its faster

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-26**:
I feel like the only people that can give you an authoritative answer would be Yujin Robot themselves. Either wait for them to post an answer/comment to this question, or open an issue over at [yujinrobot/kobuki/issues](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues). Do refer to this one, please.